# Remove N day older file from an external location using pom.xml (maven) or Hudson

Tags: java, maven, build, hudson

To keep recently created 3 zip files from external folder location on disk and delete older zip files.Maven pom.xml are executed using Hudson use to create the zip file.
How to do it using pom.xml or Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Maven can delegate to other languages inside the POM. You could use [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) and write that logic in Groovy. Or the [Ant Run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to write that logic in Ant.

At that point, you have the steps to:

1. Get a list of zip files in that folder
2. Sort them
3. Skip first three and delete others

You also probably want to have a profile so this only happens on your build server and not locally. Or points to a different location locally.

Comment: Thanks...Is there any code snippet for above shared steps to achieve it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks..any code snippet for above sudo code will be helpful. If possible can we also plan to got for java main class calling inside maven to achieve it?

Comment: Groovy can call Java so you could do that. I think it is easier to just embed the code because it is short. For that matter, you could just write the "Java" code directly and use the Groovy plugin. Why don't you try to write the logic given the pseudocode? I could write it, but so could you....

Comment: Thanks for the input...As per above sudo code implemented logic in java. AS

Comment: Is there a way to implement in Maven or ant script above logic?

Comment: I configure Hudson to call ant script. In ant script define following code in ant script:                                 <target name="deleteOldfiles">
 <tstamp>
  <format property="last.period" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"  locale="en,UK" offset="-4" unit="day" /> 
  </tstamp>
  <echo>Will delete backups builds before ${last.period}</echo> 
<delete>
 <fileset dir="${zipLocation}">
 <date datetime="${last.period}" when="before" /> 
 </fileset>
</delete>
</target>                                                         Any alternate way we can do same thing using maven?